# Growing Mouth Bacteria in a bowl of sugar water

Tags: biochemistry, bacteriology, growth-media

I want to teach my nephew why brushing in necessary and how sugar in mouth reduced by bacteria to acid.

I plan to put sugar mixed water in bowl and take swab from his mouth and dip in bowl, and test ph using Litmus paper to show him that sugar is converted to acid.

Is it possible to grow mouth acid making bacteria in this solution and will it change pH enough to show in litmus paper?

Comment: It's really going to depend on the concentration and type of microbiome... and it'll probably be more complicated than just "put bacteria in sugar water"; the concentration of sugar has to be low enough not to dehydrate the bacteria, you'll also need some salts and nitrogen source, again in low enough concentrations.  The simple answer is probably "try and see," because we don't know the exact paramaters.

Answer (score 1):

I like the concept of this demonstration for teaching science!

As rotaredom's comment pointed out, bacteria does not grow in plain water with sugar. Bacteria require a nitrogen source, trace minerals and vitamins to grow in significant numbers.

I have a few recommendations that you can try, but I attached an extensive guide to kitchen microbiology below.

1. Growing the microbes in diluted milk (~ 1:10 dilution) + salt (a pinch for half glass) with and without added sugar (1 teaspoon for half a glass) might be a good starting point. Add yeast extract if you have some (not bakers yeast, but this is the killed version of that).
2. Make sure to boil and cool the milk, the container and other ingredients to keep conditions sterile.
3. Avoid a cotton swab if you can (as the cotton might not be sterile), I would take some milk solution, swirl it in my mouth and spit it back into the same container.
4. Also have a sterile culture in the experiment, without the oral microbes for comparison and a great teaching point.
5. Grow the microbes for 2-4 days with an air permeable cap (the air allows faster growing aerobic organisms, the cap ensures dust does not fall in)

   Extensive source: [Microbiology at Home: A short non-laboratory manual for enthusiasts and bioartists](https://exploringtheinvisible.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/manual.pdf)
   PS: I'm studying PhD to be a microbiologist